# What is a Kravchuk transform and how is it related to Fourier transforms?

Tags: transform

It has been stated [here](https://phys.org/news/2019-07-quantum-technology.html), that the the so-called **Kravchuk transform** is very important in the field of image processing and possibly in signal processing in general.

I can hardly find any description about this (e.g. not mentioned in Wikipedia, etc.).

It seems to be mentioned in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/24147178_Mode_analysis_and_signal_restoration_with_Kravchuk_functions), for example.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Transliterations of  Ukrainian names have different avatars in English (and in others languages as well). You can find [Kravchuk polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kravchuk_polynomials), and other papers like  [On Krawtchouk Transforms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.1695) or [Krawtchouk polynomials and Krawtchouk matrices](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0702073). You can find as well [Kravchuk orthogonal polynomials](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01056132).

As they form an orthogonal basis of polynomials (as well as many others, listed on [polpak](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/m_src/polpak/polpak.html): Bernoulli, Bernstein, Tchebychev, Hermite, Laguerre, Legendre, Zernike), they are candidates for a transform. Derived moments are used in image processing, and the following paper seems to have a wide audience:

- [Image analysis by Krawtchouk moments](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIP.2003.818019), IEEE Transactions on Image Processing 2003

> A new set of orthogonal moments based on the discrete classical
>   Krawtchouk polynomials is introduced. The Krawtchouk polynomials are
>   scaled to ensure numerical stability, thus creating a set of weighted
>   Krawtchouk polynomials. The set of proposed Krawtchouk moments is then
>   derived from the weighted Krawtchouk polynomials. The orthogonality of
>   the proposed moments ensures minimal information redundancy. No
>   numerical approximation is involved in deriving the moments, since the
>   weighted Krawtchouk polynomials are discrete. These properties make
>   the Krawtchouk moments well suited as pattern features in the analysis
>   of two-dimensional images. It is shown that the Krawtchouk moments can
>   be employed to extract local features of an image, unlike other
>   orthogonal moments, which generally capture the global features. The
>   computational aspects of the moments using the recursive and symmetry
>   properties are discussed. The theoretical framework is validated by an
>   experiment on image reconstruction using Krawtchouk moments and the
>   results are compared to that of Zernike, pseudo-Zernike, Legendre, and
>   Tchebyscheff moments. Krawtchouk moment invariants are constructed
>   using a linear combination of geometric moment invariants; an object
>   recognition experiment shows Krawtchouk moment invariants perform
>   significantly better than Hu's moment invariants in both noise-free
>   and noisy conditions.

Later, you can read:

- [Image Analysis Using Hahn Moments](https://doi.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2007.70709), IEEE Transactions on Pattern Analysis and Machine, 2007, where Hahn moments generalize Chebyshev and Krawtchouk moments:

> This paper shows how Hahn moments provide a unified understanding of
>   the recently introduced Chebyshev and Krawtchouk moments. The two
>   latter moments can be obtained as particular cases of Hahn moments
>   with the appropriate parameter settings and this fact implies that
>   Hahn moments encompass all their properties. The aim of this paper is
>   twofold: (1) To show how Hahn moments, as a generalization of
>   Chebyshev and Krawtchouk moments, can be used for global and local
>   feature extraction and (2) to show how Hahn moments can be
>   incorporated into the framework of normalized convolution to analyze
>   local structures of irregularly sampled signals.

In [Wikipedia's Discrete Fourier transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) we find:

> The choice of eigenvectors of the DFT matrix has become important in
>   recent years in order to define a discrete analogue of the fractional
>   Fourier transform—the DFT matrix can be taken to fractional powers by
>   exponentiating the eigenvalues (e.g., Rubio and Santhanam, 2005). For
>   the continuous Fourier transform, the natural orthogonal
>   eigenfunctions are the Hermite functions, so various discrete
>   analogues of these have been employed as the eigenvectors of the DFT,
>   such as the Kravchuk polynomials (Atakishiyev and Wolf, 1997). The
>   "best" choice of eigenvectors to define a fractional discrete Fourier
>   transform remains an open question, however.

Comment: Can we said that "Kravchouk transform" usually is a "fractional Fourier transform"?

Comment: There are ambiguities on what people call "fractional Fourier transforms", and I am not a practitioner of the [Fractional Fourier–Kravchuk transform](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01056132), but I doubt there is a one-to-one correspondance

Comment: ah ok. It seems strange that they cite this obscure  Kravchouk in https://phys.org/news/2019-07-quantum-technology.html as it does not seem to be known by many DSP people ?

Comment: Honestly, I vaguely remembered Kravchouk from a past life on orthogonal polynomials, and was not aware of their so-called "huge importance" in image processing.

Comment: oh ok. So you would say it is "overstated" as important?

Comment: This is another area where keeping the distinction and relationship between the discrete and continuous case is important.  I like to use Legendre polynomials.  I tend to think of them as "the orthogonal Taylor series", however, the discrete version in not orthogonal.  You need to apply something like Gram-Schmidt (G-S) to rectify that for discrete usage.  Then keeping the same N becomes important.

Comment: A very good point to mention the difficulty in going discrete. @Machupicchu IMHO, Zernike moments are better known for images.

Comment: Hello, sorry to post here but I have a very interesting question related to ML here that nobody is answering and maybe you could ... (and since its unfortunately impossible to contact ppl directly here) ... https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/63277/adversarial-training-deep-learning-book